# Creating a Show/Detail Page in React-Redux, How to Properly Pass Down Props

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm brand new to React-Redux, I picked it up last week and was given an assignment to create a simple application where you can create, update, destroy and view posts.

I am extremely frustrated as I cannot figure out why I cannot effectively pass props into my show page.

I have a link on each post in an index page and when clicked, it is supposed to take you to the detailed page of the post.

When I go to the show page, the current post is in the State, but it never renders.

I know this is true because I am using logger middleware and there is only one post in the state, which is the one I want to render.

In my map state to props, post, which is supposed to point to the current post, is undefined, and I get an error when trying to access it. I am assuming my problem is there (in my mapStateToProps).

I feel in over my head with this material. Are there any standard guidelines to follow when creating your store/reducers, to make passing down information easier/more straight forward? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

**relevant action creators/ajax call**

```
export const receivePost = (post) => ({
  type: RECEIVE_POST,
  post
})

export const requestSinglePost = (id) => (dispatch) => (
  APIUtil.fetchSinglePost(id).then(post => dispatch(receivePost(post)))
);

export const fetchSinglePost = (id) => {
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: `api/posts/${id}`
  })
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
const postReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  Object.freeze(state);

    switch(action.type) {
      case RECEIVE_ALL_POSTS:
        return merge({}, state, action.posts)
      case RECEIVE_POST:
        const newPost = { currentPost: {[action.post.id]: action.post}}
        return merge({}, state, newPost)
      case REMOVE_POST:
        const nextState = merge({}, state);
        delete nextState[action.post.id];
        return nextState;
      default:
        return state;
    };
};

export default postReducer;
```

**rootReducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import postReducer from './post_reducer';

const RootReducer = combineReducers({
  posts: postReducer,
});

export default RootReducer;
```

**container**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PostDetailView from './post_detail_view';
import { requestSinglePost } from '../../actions/post_actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  post: state.posts.currentPost
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  requestSinglePost: id => dispatch(requestSinglePost(id))
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(PostDetailView);
```

**component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'

class PostDetailView extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestSinglePost(this.props.match.params.postId);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    if (newProps.match.params.postId !== this.props.match.params.postId) {
      this.props.requestSinglePost(newProps.match.params.postId);
    }
  }

    render () {

      if (!this.props.post) {
        return null;
      }

        return (
          <div>
            <h3>{this.props.post.title}</h3>
            <p>{this.props.post.body}</p>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }


export default PostDetailView;
```

Comment: are you getting this value `newProps.match.params.postId)`?

Comment: It seems like you're passing the props down correctly. I do notice you don't have an initial state set in the reducer other than the blank object. Maybe you could put "currentPost = []" inside of the initial state object in the reducer, and then maybe Redux will notice the change in state and re-render. Any way we can see what the logger is saying with the states?

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it to work adding another reducer to solely track current posts.

Comment: @AustinStehling, can you please post your solution as the answer so other SO members can benefit in the future.